# multiplication sum result from 2 different tables were false

Tags: php, database, sum, multiplication

i need your help..

i'm using this code to sum multiplication of two tables content (multiple data) but the result of the sum was false.

table1:
 1. id_std
 2. lecture
 3. score

table2:
 1. lecture_id
 2. credit

```
$sql_data3 = $db->database_prepare("SELECT SUM(B.credit) as credit, SUM(A.score * B.credit) as total_score, A.id_std FROM table1 A
                                            INNER JOIN table2 B ON B.lecture_id = A.lecture
                                            WHERE
                                            A.id_std = ?")->execute($data["id_std"]);

while ($data_add3 = $db->database_fetch_array($sql_data3)){
    $index = number_format($data_add3['total_score'] / $data_add3['credit'], 2);
    $credit = $data_add3['credit'];
    $score_total= $data_add3['total_score'];
```

is there any suggestion for this problem (score total and index always show false result)..?
thanks..

Comment: Add these 2 conditions to your where clause and see if it helps: `A.score IS NOT NULL AND B.credit IS NOT NULL`. I think data in your tables are not perfectly same.

Comment: @HosseinShahsahebi sorry it doesn't work. Actually, the sum of multiplication result doesn't show the true result. According to your additional condition, it just cause error (blank content) to the result.

Comment: oh, I see now, by `FALSE` you mean it respond with an incorrect answer, true? For instance, if the correct answer is 20, your query will return 10? I think your data has problem, it would be helpful if you append a sample data in your question